# Query loop with PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I had a trouble that I dealt with using multiple queries which is not very efficient. I was wondering if you maybe know an easier way.

Problem description:
Each user has an id of the person that 'invited' that user. This user can then invite someone else.

So

```
User 1 || ID 1 || Invited_by 0
User 2 || ID 2 || Invited_by 1
User 3 || ID 3 || Invited_by 1
User 4 || ID 5 || Invited_by 3
User 5 || ID 6 || Invited_by 4
```

How I can get the full list of users invited by user 1 **and users that he invited** (for example) with Mysql, php and laravel.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, you are after a list of all the users invited by user `1` and then all the users that they in turn invited?

Answer (score 1):

Okay let's suppose the Database structure is something similar to this

### Table: users

int: user_id
int: invited_by

Where `invited_by` is a foreign key that references `user_id` in the same table (`users`).

I have created the following migration to create the above database structure (p.s you are free to create it using raw MySql query)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->integer('invited_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('invited_by')
                ->references('user_id')
                ->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Then I Inserted into users table some test data as following:

user_id: 1, invited_by: null
user_id: 2, invited_by: 1
user_id: 3, invited_by: 1
user_id: 4, invited_by: 1

Now in User eloquent model I have added those two functions:

```
/**
 * Function to get the users that were invited by the current user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function invitees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'invited_by', 'user_id');
}

/**
 * Function to get the user who invited the current user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function invitedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'invited_by', 'user_id');
}
```

Now let's say if I want to know who invited user of ID 2:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', 2)->first();
$invitedByUser = $user->invitedBy()->getResults();
```

If we want to know the users that user of ID 1 invited:

```
$user = User::where('user_id', 1)->first();
$invitees = $user->invitees()->getResults();
```

I have tried it and it works as expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate, I really appreciate your answer, however my question was a bit wrong (now it's edited) but I think you might set me on right path.

Comment: @Lixi I have edited my answer to give a working example. Hope it helps and feel free to comment if you have any questions. Cheers